# jQuery File Upload and Validation undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am using **jQuery** file upload and validation but it looks like there is some conflict which I am not able to resolve. I have tried to fix it by applying `jQuery.noConflict();` but that did not help at all.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):943
(anonymous function) (index):943
m.Callbacks.j jquery.min.js:2
m.Callbacks.k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
m.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
J jquery.min.js:2
```

Code on Line 943 `var amount_input = 5;`

**Here is the jQuery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var amount_input = 5;
                jQuery('fieldset .remove-file').live('click',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery(this).parent().remove();
                });

                jQuery('#more-upload-file').bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var size = jQuery('#set_upload_file .field-row').size();
                    var template = '<span class="field-row"><label for="file_'+ ++size +'">File ( jpg, png, jpeg, gif ):</label><input type="file" id="file_'+ size +'" name="file_'+ size +'" /><a href="#" class="remove-file">remove</a></span>';
                    jQuery(template).insertBefore('#more-upload-file')
                });

                jQuery('input[id=f_full_name], input[id=f_email],input[id=f_phone],input[id=f_company]').keypress(verifyUpload);
                jQuery('input[id=f_full_name], input[id=f_email],input[id=f_phone],input[id=f_company]').change(verifyUpload);

                verifyUpload();
            });
            function verifyUpload(){
                var v1=jQuery('input[id=f_full_name]').val();
                var v2=jQuery('input[id=f_email]').val();
                var v3=jQuery('input[id=f_phone]').val();
                var v4=jQuery('input[id=f_company]').val();
                if((v1=="") || (v2=="") || (v3=="") || (v4=="") ){
                    jQuery('#filewarning').show();
                    jQuery('#set_upload_file').hide();
                }else{
                    jQuery('#filewarning').hide();
                    jQuery('#set_upload_file').show();
                }
            }
    </script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul id="filewarning" class="messages"><li class="error-msg">Please, fill the required fields above to begin file upload</li></ul>
<fieldset id="set_upload_file" style="display:none">
    <legend>Upload File</legend>
    <span class="field-row">
        <label for="file_1">File ( jpg, png, jpeg, gif ):</label>
        <input type="file" id="file_1" name="file_1" />
    </span>
    <a href="#" alt="More Files Upload" id="more-upload-file">Upload more files</a>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I suspect `.live()` not the variable :)

Comment: Could you try changing `.live()` to `.on()` for me?

Comment: ... and `.bind()` to `.on()` too

Comment: @skip405 it worked. How can I mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery v.1.7, so you need to use `.on()` instead